# Is it possible to specify that two type parameters are different types?

Tags: generics, rust

I have a simple wrapper structure with a `map` method. I also have a hierarchy of error enums where I've implemented `From` to be able to convert an `Error1` to an `Error2`, allowing the `try!` macro to automatically convert for me:

```
struct Span<T>(T);

impl<T> Span<T> {
    fn map<F, U>(self, f: F) -> Span<U>
        where F: FnOnce(F) -> U
    {
        Span(f(self.0))
    }
}

enum Error1 { One }
enum Error2 { Two }

impl From<Error1> for Error2 {
    fn from(v: Error1) -> Error2 { Error2::Two }
}
```

I'd like to be able to add a `From` implementation so that I can also automatically convert the insides of the `Span` structure:

```
impl<T,U> From<Span<T>> for Span<U>
    where U: From<T>
{
    fn from(v: Span<T>) -> Span<U> {
        v.map(|v| v.into())
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, [this fails](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=d7fc7597a54ef362de469a99ea0c1af1&version=stable):

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<Span<_>>` for type `Span<_>`:
  --> src/main.rs:18:1
   |
18 |   impl<T,U> From<Span<T>> for Span<U>
   |  _^ starting here...
19 | |     where U: From<T>
20 | | {
21 | |     fn from(v: Span<T>) -> Span<U> {
22 | |         v.map(|v| v.into())
23 | |     }
24 | | }
   | |_^ ...ending here
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`
```

The error message doesn't point to a [specific implementation of `From`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html), but my guess is it's this one:

```
impl<T> From<T> for T
```

And that my implementation could conflict if my `T` and `U` happen to be the same concrete type. Is there any way I can implement my trait for all `T` and `U` where `T` != `U`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not yet possible and the best approach to this problem has not really been decided yet. One proposal that is slightly relevant to this situation is the idea of [negative bounds](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/586) (specifically [equality bounds](https://github.com/kennytm/rfcs/blob/neg-bounds/text/0000-negative-bounds.md#syntax)), but I think it has been deemed too complex. See the [latest issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1053) on the subject for more information, where the team members are considering different ideas, including specialization.