# Unable to implement Into trait for a generic struct

Tags: generics, type-conversion, rust

I'm having trouble implementing the `Into` trait for a generic struct in Rust.  A simplified version of what I am trying to do is below:

```
struct Wrapper<T> {
    value: T
}

impl<T> Into<T> for Wrapper<T> {
    fn into(self) -> T {
        self.value
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
error: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::Into<_>` for type `Wrapper<_>`: [--explain E0119]
 --> <anon>:5:1
  |>
5 |> impl<T> Into<T> for Wrapper<T> {
  |> ^
note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`
```

I get the impression that the problem is the following implementation in the standard library:

```
impl<T, U> Into<T> for U where T: From<U>
```

Since `T` *might* implement `From<Wrapper<T>>`, this *might* be a conflicting implementation.  Is there any way around this problem?  For example, is there a way to have an `impl<T>` block restricting `T` to types that do not implement `From<Wrapper<T>>`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/30427927/155423.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually... there isn't a way to restrict this to types `T` not implementing `From<Wrapper<T>>`. Rust does not have "negative" clauses.

Normally, the way to implement `Into` is simply to implement `From` and get `Into` *for free*. However, in your case the implementation would be:

```
impl<T> From<Wrapper<T>> for T {
    fn from(w: Wrapper<T>) -> T { w.value }
}
```

and this runs into the orphan rules. You are not allowed to implement `From` for all `T`.

There might be a trick, but I cannot see it here.