# How should I implement From/Into for my struct with one generic parameter bound by my trait?

Tags: generics, rust

https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/pg3wqr

```rust
trait A {}

struct B<T: A>(T);

// this is ok
impl<T: A> From<T> for B<T> {
    fn from(t: T) -> Self { B(t) }
}

// this is not ok
impl<T: A> From<B<T>> for T {
    fn from(b: B<T>) -> Self { b.0 }
}
```

I get:

> error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`B<T>`)

This is not really helping (neither did searching this error message).
What I wanted to achieve seems pretty straightforward. Why is this not allowed, and how can I work around the limitations?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39186717/4876553 basically recommended the same thing, without the bound on the impl, which fails to compile in the same manner.

EDIT: I accidentally copy-pasted a WIP version of me trying to work around this; fixed back to the original example.

Comment: What you want to do is add a method `from` to *every* type which converts to yours. Rust's orphan rules won't allow this, because someone else might come along and (unknowingly) write a conflicting implementation. You don't own those types, so Rust forbids it. The orphan rules are fairly generous, but they won't let you add blanket impls to things you don't control.

Comment: Looks like you can't implement `Into` directly, either.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: Both `trait A` and `struct B` are defined in my crate. While someone else might `impl A` for their type, shouldn't _my_ definitions take precedence?

Comment: No, because you're trying to take away the ability for another crate to implement `From` for their own type. You don't own either of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust's orphan rules don't allow it. The exact covering semantics are complicated (if you're interested, [this article](https://github.com/Ixrec/rust-orphan-rules) is a good jumping-off point), but the basic idea is this:

Take all of the type and trait names passed to an `impl` in order, starting with the trait itself, then to the structure or enum we're writing an `impl` for, then any type arguments. So with the `impl` written as

```
impl<T> MyTrait<Bar, Baz, T> for Foo
```

we would write `MyTrait, Foo, Bar, Baz, T` (where `T` is a type variable).

Now, in this list we've written, find the first name that is defined in our own crate. If the trait is defined in our own crate, then that's the name. If `Foo` is, then take that one. Otherwise, keep going until you find one. If there are no names defined in the current crate, fail because we have an orphan instance. In this example, let's pretend `MyTrait` is defined somewhere else but `Foo` is our own. Then we have

```
MyTrait, Foo, Bar, Baz, T
         ^^^
```

Anything *before* the name we just found must be concrete, i.e. it can't be a generic type argument. In our example here, the only type argument is `T`, and it occurs after `Foo`, so it's fine.

(Note that I'm also glossing over *covered types*. That is, an impl on `&Foo` is, for the orphan purposes, considered an impl on `Foo`. This applies to references, `Box`, and several other built-in `Box`-like types; it *never* applies to types you define yourself)

Now let's take a look at your examples. Things get more complicated when we add generics, and I'm not going to go over all of the messy technical details here, so we'll try to keep it as simple as possible.

```
impl<T: A> From<T> for B<T>
```

Here, the trait is `From`, the type we're implementing is `B`, and our type argument to `From` is `T`. Our list is

```
From, B, T
```

Note that although we're implementing for `B<T>`, we say `T` is *covered* by the `B` type, so we only take the top-level `B`, not what's inside.

Now `From` is standard library, so we don't own it, but `B` is in our crate. So we have

```
From, B, T
      ^
```

Then we look for generic arguments. The only type argument here is `T`, and it appears *after* the `B` that we own, so we're good.

Now the other one.

```
impl<T: A> From<B<T>> for T
```

The trait is `From`, as before. The first type is `T`, a generic type argument. Then `B<T>` is next.

```
From, T, B
```

Again, we write `B`, not `B<T>`, since we only care about *uncovered types*.

`From` is standard library, and `T` is a type argument, so `B` is the only thing we own here.

```
From, T, B
         ^
```

But there's a type argument `T` *before* the first thing we own! That's a problem, so this fails by Rust's orphan rules.

The *reason* the rules are written this way is to prevent two sibling crates (i.e. crates who are not aware of each other) from accidentally implementing conflicting instances. If we allowed

```
impl<T: A> From<B<T>> for T
```

then someone else might come along one day and write

```
impl<T> From<T> for C
```

for some type `C` in their own crate. They're well within their rights to do so: `C` is their own type and the only generic argument occurs *after* `C` in their trait argument list. But then there are two candidate solutions for `impl From<B<C>> for C`. (Note that trait bounds, i.e. `T: A` are taken into consideration *much* later and are not considered at this point, since that would just make the already complex problem of trait resolution completely untenable).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So if I understand correctly, `From` (and therefore `Into`) is effectively unimplementable for generic adapter types like `B` in my example?

Comment: You can (as you've already done) engineer it so that `B::from(x)` works for any `x`. However, making `SomeType::from(y)` work for any adaptor `y: B<T>` is not doable.

Answer (score -1):

Edit. This still down't work because of the orphan rule. The answer by Silvio also explains why this code doesn't work.

Old comment below

> In your implementation you are using `from(u: U)`. The way you have your code written `U` isn't a generic type because you haven't declared it in the impl block. The only generic type available is `T`.
> In the function you need to use a parameter that is of type B. You have declared B as a tuple struct with its 1 and only field being of generic type T which must implement trait A. So to get that t back out of B you need to call b.0 which is the syntax to get the value out of a tuple struct.
> You also need to make that field accessible so you need to change the struct definition to

```rust
struct B<T: A>(pub T);
```

> and then change the impl block to this

```rust
impl<T: A> From<B<T>> for T {
    fn from(b: B<T>) -> T { 
        b.0 
    }
}
```

> The function definition could also return `Self`  e.g. `fn from(b: B) -> Self {...}` because in this impl block Self is the same as T.

Comment: Sorry I might have made a mistake in copy and paste; however even after fixing it, as the other answer explained, your solution does not compile either.

Comment: Ohh I see my mistake. The answer by Silvio explains it well. The way my code is written there is no guarantee that T is a type defined in the current crate therefore it is considered foreign and cannot impl the foreign trait From.