# Error: "type parameter T must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (Vector3D)"

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust. The code bellow is my attempt to code a simple program that handles 3D Vectors operation. Here I'm showing only the implementation of the product between a scalar and a 3D vector. My goals are:

1. use the operator * for multiplication in both order 'vector * scalar' and 'scalar * vector' such that I can write complex vector equations without caring about order of operation.
2. use generic types to allow scalar be any numeric type (integer or float) and convert it to f64 inside the implementation before the calculations.

This is a example of part of my code.

```
use std::ops::Mul;

fn v3d<Tx, Ty, Tz>(x: Tx, y: Ty, z: Tz) -> Vector3D 
    where
        Tx: Into<f64>,
        Ty: Into<f64>,
        Tz: Into<f64>,
{
    Vector3D {
        x: x.into(),
        y: y.into(),
        z: z.into(),
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct Vector3D {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    z: f64,
}

//this implementation of Mul works fine!
// Vector3D * T -> Vector3D
impl<T: Into<f64> + Copy> Mul<T> for Vector3D {
    type Output = Vector3D;

    fn mul(self, other: T) -> Vector3D {
        Vector3D {
            x: other.into() * self.x,
            y: other.into() * self.y,
            z: other.into() * self.z,
        }
    }
}

//this implementation of Mul does not compile!
// T * `enter code here`Vector3D -> Vector3D      
impl<T: Into<f64> + Copy> Mul<Vector3D> for T {
    type Output = Vector3D;

    fn mul(self, other: Vector3D) -> Vector3D {
        Vector3D {
            x: self.into() * other.x,
            y: self.into() * other.y,
            z: self.into() * other.z,
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let v = v3d(1, -3, 0.5);
    let u = v3d(-1.0, 2.1, 0.0);
    let d = v * 3;
    let e = 2.0 * u;
    println!("{:?}", v);
    println!("{:?}", u);
    println!("{:?}", d);
    println!("{:?}", e);
}
```

I'm able to get the 'vector * scalar' implementation correctly. However, the implementation of 'scalar * vector' gives me the error

```
 impl<T: Into<f64> + Copy> Mul<Vector3D> for T {
      ^ type parameter `T` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`Vector3D`)
```

I've seen this error been explained [with Rust's orphan rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73790215/how-should-i-implement-from-into-for-my-struct-with-one-generic-parameter-bound). Covering the generic type by placing it into a tuple (T,) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63131661/5568603) does not compile as well with the error

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src\main.rs:73:21
   |
73 |             x: self.into() * other.x,
   |                     ^^^^
   |
help: try using a fully qualified path to specify the expected types
   |
73 |             x: <(T,) as Into<T>>::into(self) * other.x,
   |                ++++++++++++++++++++++++    ~

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src\main.rs:73:21
   |
73 |             x: self.into() * other.x,
   |                     ^^^^   - type must be known at this point
   |
note: multiple `impl`s satisfying `_: Mul<f64>` found
```

However I did not find any workaround this. It seems such a simple problem but has take me hours looking without no solution.