# Implementing Mul for a generic struct

Tags: generics, rust, traits

So I have a struct

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Polynomial {
    pub coefficients: Vec<BIG>,
}
```

It has 2 MulAssign methods as follows

```
impl<B: Borrow<Self>> ops::MulAssign<B> for Polynomial {...} 
impl ops::MulAssign<BIG> for Polynomial {...}
```

all pretty standard so far. All of this compiles and works as intended.

I am reimplementing this using generics so we can have polynomials of any type that implement Big. Specifically, we have a trait Trait with type big implementing Big. Trait also holds other traits that would need to be consistent with big.

```
trait Trait {
    type big: Big; // this makes sure big works the same as BIG
    type othertype: OtherType<big = Self::big>;
    ...
}
```

I attempted to create a generic polynomial for trait as below. Note that _Polynomial must be generic on Trait since some other functions (say for othertype) may need a polynomial using the same kind of Big.

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct _Polynomial<T: Trait> {
    pub coefficients: Vec<T::big>,
}
```

I also tried to recreate the MulAssign functions with headers below, and here is where my issue arises

```
impl<T: Curve, B: Borrow<Self>> ops::MulAssign<B> for _Polynomial<T> {...}
impl<T: Curve> ops::MulAssign<T::big> for _Polynomial<T> {...}
```

I get an error "conflicting implementation for `polynomial::_Polynomial<_>`".

I mostly understand WHY this is happening ([Conflicting implementations of trait in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159226/conflicting-implementations-of-trait-in-rust), [Unable to implement Into trait for a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186652/unable-to-implement-into-trait-for-a-generic-struct)) but I couldn't get the work around in those posts, or any of the other workarounds I found online.

I am still confused about why the initial version compiles without any errors since the method could be considered overloaded (how do we know "BIG" doesn't implement Borrow?)

I have spent many hours working at this and while I feel like I've learned a lot digging through stack overflow posts I still haven't found a workaround that works.

Any and all help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: *"how do we know "BIG" doesn't implement Borrow?"* - I assume `BIG` is something defined in your crate and only your crate is allowed to implement `Borrow<Polynomial> for BIG` and thus the compiler has full knowledge that it doesn't conflict.

Comment: Correct, BIG is defined in the crate. Confirming my understanding of why the generic case doesn't work, we can't say that we know T::big doesn't implement Borrow<_Polynomial<T>> in the same way since we don't know T and thus T::big at compile time?